# Sakai Preference Tool

Tags: sakai

Am not able to see preference tool in Sakai2.8.2. Is there any configuration to enable preferene tool in sakai?

Please do let me know if anything is required for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

By default the Sakai administrator has a My Workspace that is the same as the administration workspace and doesn't contain a preferences tool. If you create a normal user when visiting Mt Workspace for the first time a copy of the site with ID `!user`will be created.

You can look at the site with the Sites tool in the Administration Workspace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.  I want to change the language of sakai . so I need the preference tool. How do I make visible to administrator?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a discussion tool. If you want to know how to change the default language in Sakai start a new question.